# Problem decoding data from json with a specific structure

Tags: ios, swift, jsondecoder

I'm trying to decode this response data:

```
{
  "headers": {},
  "original": {
      "code": 201,
      "success": true,
      "message": "Message"
  },
  "exception": null
}
```

With this struct:

```
struct MarcaAguaResData: Codable {
    let original: Marca
}

struct Marca: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
}
```

I only care about what is in original. With the code that I'm implementing, using a JSONDecoder, I get this error:

```
failure(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "code", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"code\", intValue: nil) (\"code\").", underlyingError: nil)))
```

Comment: I cannot confirm this with a simple copy and paste. What I can see, however, is that your json is malformed (missing comma after `"success": true`). It does not match the error but you might consider correcting it

Comment: That was my mistake. I corrected the question

Comment: The question basically is: What structure should I use to decode that JSON data?

Comment: The struct that you provided is suitable to decode the json you provided. The error has to be a different one

Comment: Do you get one element in your json response or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that **the JSON you provided and the Codable you provided works just fine**.

But, as you are getting this specific error:

> failure(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "code", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "code", intValue: nil) ("code").", underlyingError: nil)))

it just means that **your server is not sending the JSON you are always expecting**, so essentially in this error your server is sending you this kind of JSON:

```
{
  "headers": {},
  "original": {
      "success": true,
      "message": "Message"
  },
  "exception": null
}
```

where the "code" is totally missing in the JSON.

**You could avoid getting the error** and still getting your code to work if you mark `code` as optional in your struct:

```
struct Marca: Codable {
    let code: Int?
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
}
```